# Local to UTC Time zone conversion when the date and time is split

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server

In my HTML input forms I have 4 fields: StartDate, EndDate, StartTime, EndTime.

Most of my users are in Eastern Time Zone and my database stores all dates in UTC. The client can send a UTC time stamp by doing something like this:

```
utcStartDateAndTime = new Date(`${startDate} ${startTime}`).toISOString();
```

There are lots of examples online that shows how to covert local timestamp to UTC. The way I want the date filter to be interpreted is that if the users fills out start date, end date, start time and end time it should filter all values between start and end date with time stamp between start and end time instead of all values that start with start date start time and ends on or before end date end time.

Now, I can combine the start date and time to find out if the utc date starts before the local date that the client entered and I can combine end date end time and do the conversion to utc to find out if the end date overflows to the next day. I can then extract the time from that utc start date and time:

```
utcStartTime = utcStartDateAndTime.split('T')[1];
utcEndTime = utcEndDateAndTime.split('T')[1];
```

My question is how do I search for records in the database now. If a user in easter time zone says I want all info between 2 dates that is between 7 pm and 11 pm the utc time becomes 11 pm to 3 am. My query cannot be

```
SELECT * FROM Records WHERE CAST(TimeStamp as Date) IS Between '${utcStartDate}' AND '${utcEndDate} 23:59:59.999' AND CAST(TimeStamp as Time) Between '${utcStartTime}' and '${utcEndTime}'
```

This is returning 0 records understandably because no date will have any record that starts at 11 pm and ends at 3 am. I cannot find my way out of this problem and maybe my whole approach is incorrect.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.